# Sagemaker Object2Vec training samples per second

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-sagemaker

I am using Sagemaker Object2Vec to train on data of size 2GB.

ml.p2.xlarge instance took 12 hours to train the data on 4 epochs going at the speed of 5000 samples/sec.

Now, I am using a higher level instance ml.p2.16xlarge and it only trains at 400 samples/sec with this in the logs

```
[06:03:49] /opt/brazil-pkg-cache/packages/AIAlgorithmsMXNet/AIAlgorithmsMXNet-1.3.x_Cuda_10.1.x.672.0/AL2012/generic-flavor/src/src/kvstore/././comm.h:739: only 114 out of 240 GPU pairs are enabled direct access. It may affect the performance. You can set MXNET_ENABLE_GPU_P2P=0 to turn it off

2020-07-27T23:03:49.956-07:00
[06:03:49] /opt/brazil-pkg-cache/packages/AIAlgorithmsMXNet/AIAlgorithmsMXNet-1.3.x_Cuda_10.1.x.672.0/AL2012/generic-flavor/src/src/kvstore/././comm.h:748: .vvvvvvvv.......

2020-07-27T23:03:49.956-07:00
[06:03:49] /opt/brazil-pkg-cache/packages/AIAlgorithmsMXNet/AIAlgorithmsMXNet-1.3.x_Cuda_10.1.x.672.0/AL2012/generic-flavor/src/src/kvstore/././comm.h:748: v.vvvvvvv.......

2020-07-27T23:03:49.956-07:00
[06:03:49] /opt/brazil-pkg-cache/packages/AIAlgorithmsMXNet/AIAlgorithmsMXNet-1.3.x_Cuda_10.1.x.672.0/AL2012/generic-flavor/src/src/kvstore/././comm.h:748: vv.vvvvvv.......

2020-07-27T23:03:49.956-07:00
[06:03:49] /opt/brazil-pkg-cache/packages/AIAlgorithmsMXNet/AIAlgorithmsMXNet-1.3.x_Cuda_10.1.x.672.0/AL2012/generic-flavor/src/src/kvstore/././comm.h:748: vvv.vvvvv.......

2020-07-27T23:03:49.956-07:00
[06:03:49] /opt/brazil-pkg-cache/packages/AIAlgorithmsMXNet/AIAlgorithmsMXNet-1.3.x_Cuda_10.1.x.672.0/AL2012/generic-flavor/src/src/kvstore/././comm.h:748: vvvv.vvvv.......

2020-07-27T23:03:49.956-07:00
[06:03:49] /opt/brazil-pkg-cache/packages/AIAlgorithmsMXNet/AIAlgorithmsMXNet-1.3.x_Cuda_10.1.x.672.0/AL2012/generic-flavor/src/src/kvstore/././comm.h:748: vvvvv.vvv.......

2020-07-27T23:03:49.956-07:00
[06:03:49] /opt/brazil-pkg-cache/packages/AIAlgorithmsMXNet/AIAlgorithmsMXNet-1.3.x_Cuda_10.1.x.672.0/AL2012/generic-flavor/src/src/kvstore/././comm.h:748: vvvvvv.vv.......

2020-07-27T23:03:49.956-07:00
[06:03:49] /opt/brazil-pkg-cache/packages/AIAlgorithmsMXNet/AIAlgorithmsMXNet-1.3.x_Cuda_10.1.x.672.0/AL2012/generic-flavor/src/src/kvstore/././comm.h:748: vvvvvvv.v.......

2020-07-27T23:03:49.956-07:00
[06:03:49] /opt/brazil-pkg-cache/packages/AIAlgorithmsMXNet/AIAlgorithmsMXNet-1.3.x_Cuda_10.1.x.672.0/AL2012/generic-flavor/src/src/kvstore/././comm.h:748: vvvvvvvv........

2020-07-27T23:03:49.956-07:00
[06:03:49] /opt/brazil-pkg-cache/packages/AIAlgorithmsMXNet/AIAlgorithmsMXNet-1.3.x_Cuda_10.1.x.672.0/AL2012/generic-flavor/src/src/kvstore/././comm.h:748: ..........vvvvvv

2020-07-27T23:03:49.956-07:00
[06:03:49] /opt/brazil-pkg-cache/packages/AIAlgorithmsMXNet/AIAlgorithmsMXNet-1.3.x_Cuda_10.1.x.672.0/AL2012/generic-flavor/src/src/kvstore/././comm.h:748: .........v.vvvvv

2020-07-27T23:03:49.956-07:00
[06:03:49] /opt/brazil-pkg-cache/packages/AIAlgorithmsMXNet/AIAlgorithmsMXNet-1.3.x_Cuda_10.1.x.672.0/AL2012/generic-flavor/src/src/kvstore/././comm.h:748: .........vv.vvvv

2020-07-27T23:03:49.956-07:00
[06:03:49] /opt/brazil-pkg-cache/packages/AIAlgorithmsMXNet/AIAlgorithmsMXNet-1.3.x_Cuda_10.1.x.672.0/AL2012/generic-flavor/src/src/kvstore/././comm.h:748: .........vvv.vvv

2020-07-27T23:03:49.956-07:00
[06:03:49] /opt/brazil-pkg-cache/packages/AIAlgorithmsMXNet/AIAlgorithmsMXNet-1.3.x_Cuda_10.1.x.672.0/AL2012/generic-flavor/src/src/kvstore/././comm.h:748: .........vvvv.vv

2020-07-27T23:03:49.956-07:00
[06:03:49] /opt/brazil-pkg-cache/packages/AIAlgorithmsMXNet/AIAlgorithmsMXNet-1.3.x_Cuda_10.1.x.672.0/AL2012/generic-flavor/src/src/kvstore/././comm.h:748: .........vvvvv.v

2020-07-27T23:03:49.956-07:00
[06:03:49] /opt/brazil-pkg-cache/packages/AIAlgorithmsMXNet/AIAlgorithmsMXNet-1.3.x_Cuda_10.1.x.672.0/AL2012/generic-flavor/src/src/kvstore/././comm.h:748: .........vvvvvv.
```

There are about 50 million samples.

What can I do to correct this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

2 ideas:

1. Before increasing the GPU count, grow batch size so that a single
   GPU is as busy as possible
2. Use P3 instances instead of P2. P3 is more recent, has more memory, more CUDA cores, faster memory bandwidth and NVLink inter-GPU connections. Though it's more
   expensive by hour, your total training cost may be much smaller if
   properly tuned

Also, if your problem involves sparse updates, meaning if just a small fraction of all tokens appear in a given mini-batch, you can try using `token_embedding_storage_type = 'row_sparse'`, which I think refers to using sparse gradient updates like described here https://medium.com/apache-mxnet/learning-embeddings-for-music-recommendation-with-mxnets-sparse-api-5698f4d7d8

Comment: Increasing the mini batch size and changing token_embedding_storage_type to row_sparse worked. Thanks!